# aws emr zeppelin doesn't have jdbc interpreter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I created a aws emr cluster with hadoop, spark and zeppelin.
Following the document https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/interpreter/jdbc.html , which says

> Fill Interpreter name field with whatever you want to use as the
>   alias(e.g. mysql, mysql2, hive, redshift, and etc..). Please note that
>   this alias will be used as %interpreter_name to call the interpreter
>   in the paragraph. Then select jdbc as an Interpreter group.

But `jdbc` option didn't show :
[image]

The emr zeppelin version is `/usr/lib/zeppelin/zeppelin-web-0.8.0.war` I have checked.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

This answer was resolved in the [AWS thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=800544&tstart=0).

TLDR; just run the following line and restart Zeppelin:

`sudo /usr/lib/zeppelin/bin/install-interpreter.sh -n jdbc`

Then Restart Zeppelin with:

```
sudo stop zeppelin
sudo start zeppelin
```